# Jenkins Pipeline, getting runWrapper references even on failed runs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run multiple builds in parallel in jenkins pipeline and get the result of those builds. My code looks something like

```
runWrappers = []

script {
    def builds = [:]
    builds['a'] = { runWrappers += build job: 'jobA', parameters: /* params here*/ }
    builds['b'] = { runWrappers += build job: 'jobB', parameters: /* params here*/ }
    builds['c'] = { runWrappers += build job: 'jobC', parameters: /* params here*/ }
    builds['d'] = { runWrappers += build job: 'jobD', parameters: /* params here*/ }

    parallel builds
    // All the builds are ran in parallel and do not exit early if one fails
    // Multiple of the builds could fail on this step
}
```

If there are no failures, the pipeline continues onto other stages.  If there is a failure, an exception will be thrown and the following post-build code will run immediately

```
post {
    always {
        script {
            def summary = ''
            for (int i; i < runWrappers.size(); i++) {
                def result = runWrappers[i].getResult()
                def link = runWrappers[i].getAbsoluteUrl()
                summary += "Build at: " + link + " had result of: " + result
            }
            /* Code to send summary to external location */
        }
    }
}
```

This works for the most part. The problem is that this code will only print out the result for the builds that result in a SUCCESS because the builds that fail throw an exception before returning a reference to a runWrapper.

Is there a way to get a reference to a runWrapper or similar that can give me information (mainly the url and result) on a failed build? Or is there a way for me to get such a reference before I start the build and cause an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `propagate: false`:

```
build job: 'jobA', propagate: false, parameters: /* params here*/
```

But in this case your `parallel` won't fail anymore.